# Can't seee ClickOnce error before window closes

Tags: c#, deployment, command-line, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce cmd line app that is throwing an exception on initialise. I can't see details of the exception because the console window closes before I can see it.

I have tried launching (my using the shortcut from the start menu, simply dropping it on to the console window) but it launches a separate console, writes the error to that and closes!

How can I see the error?!

Thanks

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend tracking down the executable in the ClickOnce cache and double-clicking on it to see if it's a ClickOnce problem or a problem in your application.

The cache is in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\obfuscatedfolder\obfuscatedfolder and from there you'll have to look in the folders for the one with your exe in it.

If it works, then it's a bug in your app. I'd put some messageboxes or logging in your app, or put in a try-catch around the start routine and have it show the exception and prompt the user for input in order to continue.

If it doesn't work, I would install .NET 4 on the machine and enable the enhanced ClickOnce logging and then check out the log file. (Note: The app does not have to target .NET 4, it just has to be installed on the machine.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little quick & dirty solution:

Use a .bat file.

In the first line launch the shortcut, the second line is just a pause.

```
start shortcut_name
pause
```

Here is [good](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm) link if you're not familiar using with .bat files